# PySpark Parallelism

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am new to spark and am trying to implement reading data from a parquet file and then after some transformation returning it to web ui as a paginated way. Everything works no issue there.

So now I want to improve the performance of my application, after some google and stack search I found out about pyspark parallelism.

What I know is that :

1. pyspark parallelism works by default and It creates a parallel process based on the number of cores the system has.
2. Also for this to work data should be partitioned.

Please correct me if my understanding is not right.

Questions/doubt:

1. I am reading data from one parquet file, so my data is not partitioned and if I use the `.repartition()` method on my dataframe that is expensive. so how should I use PySpark Parallelism here ?
2. Also I could not find any simple implementation of pyspark parallelism, which could explain how to use it.

Comment: Where are you running this process? On a single computer or a cluster of machines?

Comment: Please focus on one question. There are no question currently in your problem. Also, include [Reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Mortz, yes I am running on single computer right now.

Comment: @Steven, I want to do that but my 2nd question is related to that point only, I could not find anything which can say this is pyspark parallelism example. so my questions  are mostly theory.

Answer (score 0):

In spark cluster 1 core reads one partition so if you are on multinode spark cluster
then you need to leave some meory for existing system manager like Yarn etc.

https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html

you can use reparation and specify number of partitions

df.repartition(n)

where n is the number of partition. Repartition is for parlelleism, it will be ess expensive then process your single file without any partition.